# ofstream inside array writes to same file all the time

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've a structure like in below:
std::list -> Includes list of objects in type of VolataliteAnalyzer *(Which is my custom class) -> VolataliteAnalyzer object keeps a ofstream object as in below code. And I'm calling the below method to write appropriate files

```
void VolataliteAnalyzer::writeToFile (unsigned long orderBookId,double volatalite,double currentWarrantPrice,double stockPrice,double expireDate,double strikePrice)
{

    logger.logMessage(new MessageInfoLog(std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)+" Writing File For :"+std::to_string(orderBookId)));
    if (!warrantFile.is_open()) {
        std::string filePath = std::string(FILE_NAME)+std::string("_")+std::to_string(orderBookId)+std::string(FILE_EXT);
        warrantFile.open (filePath,std::ios_base::app);
        logger.logMessage(new MessageInfoLog(std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)+" Creating File:"+filePath));

    }

    warrantFile << this->getCurrentDate()+DELIMETER+std::to_string(volatalite)+DELIMETER+std::to_string(currentWarrantPrice)+DELIMETER+std::to_string(stockPrice)+DELIMETER+std::to_string(expireDate)+DELIMETER+std::to_string(strikePrice)+"\n";

}
```

However when I call this method , for different objects in the array , it always writes to same file . But instead it should write to unique files for each object in array. I've tested it many times but wasnt able to understand the reason. I suspected that if  ofstream objects are singleton  or something like that?

```
class VolataliteAnalyzer {

public:

    double selectedVolatalite=0;

    VolataliteAnalyzer();
    void writeToFile(unsigned long orderBookId,double volatalite,double currentWarrantPrice,double stockPrice,double expireDate,double strikePrice);
    void finishWriting();
    bool loadFromFile(unsigned long orderBookId);
    void getSelectedVolatalite(int dayCount);

private:
        Logger& logger;
        std::ofstream warrantFile;
        std::ifstream warrantReader;
        std::string getCurrentDate();
        std::list<Volatalite *> dailyVolatalites;

        Volatalite* getVolatalite(std::string date);
};
```

Comment: The initial call to `writeToFile` will open the file. Then no matter how many calls to `writeToFile` you do, and no matter how many times you change `orderBookId`, the function will not create a new file. It will always use the same file, created by the very first call. Unless you destroy the `VolataliteAnalyzer` object of course. Perhaps you should not keep the file stream object as a member, and instead open for *appending* each and every call? Then if you change `orderBookId` it will write to a different file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's an answer, not a comment